# Find second max value in the moving window frame using SQL / BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a requirement to calculate the second max value in the moving window of the past 120 minutes frame just like I have calculated max value in past 120 minutes moving frame partitioned on device_id.

MAX(Temperature) OVER(PARTITION BY device_type ORDER BY event_ts_seconds RANGE BETWEEN 7200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Max_Temp_in_120frame

Similarly, I want to calculate the second max temperature.

[image]

I have tried the below 2 versions of NTH_VALUE but it is not working as expected.

NTH_VALUE(Temperature,2) OVER(PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY event_ts_seconds RANGE BETWEEN 7200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SecondMax_Temp_in_120frame

NTH_VALUE(Temperature,2) OVER(PARTITION BY device_id ORDER BY Temperature DESC RANGE BETWEEN 7200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS SecondMax_Temp_in_120frame

Help on this will be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short Answer

You can do it like this:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 
    ts,
    ROUND(10*RAND(), 1) as value
  FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10)) ts
)
, sample_with_moving_array AS (
    SELECT
        ts,
        value,
        ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_array,
    FROM sample
)
, sample_with_sorted_moving_array AS (
    SELECT
        ts,
        value,
        moving_array,
        ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(moving_array) as value ORDER BY value DESC) as sorted_moving_array
    FROM sample_with_moving_array
)
SELECT
    ts,
    value,
    sorted_moving_array[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS max_value_in_3_frame_alternate_version,
    sorted_moving_array[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS second_max_value_in_3_frame,
FROM sample_with_sorted_moving_array
```

#### Explanation

First of all, `NTH_VALUE` won't work because it is a generalization of the window function `FIRST_VALUE`, not `MAX`.

In BigQuery, you can compute the second max value in three steps.
First, use `ARRAY_AGG` to compute the moving array of values:

```sql
ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_array
```

This will give you something like this:

| ts | value | moving_array_as_string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | [0.6] |
| 2 | 5.4 | [0.6, 5.4] |
| 3 | 5.4 | [0.6, 5.4, 5.4] |
| 4 | 5.9 | [0.6, 5.4, 5.4, 5.9] |
| 5 | 4.6 | [5.4, 5.4, 5.9, 4.6] |
| 6 | 6 | [5.4, 5.9, 4.6, 6] |
| 7 | 8.7 | [5.9, 4.6, 6, 8.7] |
| 8 | 3.5 | [4.6, 6, 8.7, 3.5] |
| 9 | 4 | [6, 8.7, 3.5, 4] |
| 10 | 0.7 | [8.7, 3.5, 4, 0.7] |

Once you have that, sort the array using an `UNNEST` like this:

```sql
ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(moving_array) as value ORDER BY value DESC) as sorted_moving_array
```

This will give you something like this (I did not display the rank, but you can see the values have been sorted inside each array):

| ts | value | sorted_moving_array_as_string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | [0.6] |
| 2 | 5.4 | [5.4, 0.6] |
| 3 | 5.4 | [5.4, 5.4, 0.6] |
| 4 | 5.9 | [5.9, 5.4, 5.4, 0.6] |
| 5 | 4.6 | [5.9, 5.4, 5.4, 4.6] |
| 6 | 6 | [6, 5.9, 5.4, 4.6] |
| 7 | 8.7 | [8.7, 6, 5.9, 4.6] |
| 8 | 3.5 | [8.7, 6, 4.6, 3.5] |
| 9 | 4 | [8.7, 6, 4, 3.5] |
| 10 | 0.7 | [8.7, 4, 3.5, 0.7] |

Finally, you can get the second element of the `sorted_moving_array` like this:

```sql
sorted_moving_array[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] second_max_value_in_3_frame
```

`ORDINAL` means you consider the array's index starts at 1 instead of 0. I find it more readable to get the 2nd element with `ORDINAL(2)` rather than `OFFSET(1)`. `SAFE_` means you want it to return a `NULL` if the index is out of the array's bound, instead of throwing an error.

The final query looks like this:

```sql
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT 
    ts,
    ROUND(10*RAND(), 1) as value
  FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 10)) ts
)
, sample_with_moving_array AS (
    SELECT
        ts,
        value,
        ARRAY_AGG(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_array,
    FROM sample
)
, sample_with_sorted_moving_array AS (
    SELECT
        ts,
        value,
        moving_array,
        ARRAY(SELECT value FROM UNNEST(moving_array) as value ORDER BY value DESC) as sorted_moving_array
    FROM sample_with_moving_array
)
SELECT
    ts,
    value,
    MAX(value) OVER(ORDER BY ts RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS max_value_in_3_frame,
    sorted_moving_array[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS max_value_in_3_frame_alternate_version,
    sorted_moving_array[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS second_max_value_in_3_frame,
    CONCAT("[", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT CAST(value as STRING) FROM UNNEST(moving_array) value), ", "), "]") AS moving_array_as_string,
    CONCAT("[", ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT CAST(value as STRING) FROM UNNEST(sorted_moving_array) value), ", "), "]") AS sorted_moving_array_as_string
FROM sample_with_sorted_moving_array
```

Which returns:

| ts | value | max_value_in_3_frame | max_value_in_3_frame_alternate_version | second_max_value_in_3_frame | moving_array_as_string | sorted_moving_array_as_string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.6 | 0.6 | 0.6 | null | [0.6] | [0.6] |
| 2 | 5.4 | 5.4 | 5.4 | 0.6 | [0.6, 5.4] | [5.4, 0.6] |
| 3 | 5.4 | 5.4 | 5.4 | 5.4 | [0.6, 5.4, 5.4] | [5.4, 5.4, 0.6] |
| 4 | 5.9 | 5.9 | 5.9 | 5.4 | [0.6, 5.4, 5.4, 5.9] | [5.9, 5.4, 5.4, 0.6] |
| 5 | 4.6 | 5.9 | 5.9 | 5.4 | [5.4, 5.4, 5.9, 4.6] | [5.9, 5.4, 5.4, 4.6] |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 5.9 | [5.4, 5.9, 4.6, 6] | [6, 5.9, 5.4, 4.6] |
| 7 | 8.7 | 8.7 | 8.7 | 6 | [5.9, 4.6, 6, 8.7] | [8.7, 6, 5.9, 4.6] |
| 8 | 3.5 | 8.7 | 8.7 | 6 | [4.6, 6, 8.7, 3.5] | [8.7, 6, 4.6, 3.5] |
| 9 | 4 | 8.7 | 8.7 | 6 | [6, 8.7, 3.5, 4] | [8.7, 6, 4, 3.5] |
| 10 | 0.7 | 8.7 | 8.7 | 4 | [8.7, 3.5, 4, 0.7] | [8.7, 4, 3.5, 0.7] |

As a control measure, I also computed the max value with the old and new methods to check I had the same results with both.

To conclude, you are lucky to be on BigQuery, as I don't think other SQL engines support all the capabilities used in this query, at least not with such an elegant syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
SELECT * EXCEPT(Array_Temp_in_120frame, Two_Max_Temp_in_120frame),
  Two_Max_Temp_in_120frame[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] Max_Temp_in_120frame, 
  Two_Max_Temp_in_120frame[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] SecondMax_Temp_in_120frame 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ARRAY(
      SELECT Temperature FROM t.Array_Temp_in_120frame Temperature
      ORDER BY Temperature DESC LIMIT 2
    ) Two_Max_Temp_in_120frame
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ARRAY_AGG(Temperature) OVER(
        PARTITION BY device_type ORDER BY event_ts_seconds 
        RANGE BETWEEN 7200 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
      ) AS Array_Temp_in_120frame
    FROM your_table
  ) t
)
```